# Can I keep xDB in MS SQL database when upgrading from 9.1 to 9.2?

Tags: upgrade

We are about to upgrade a solution from `Sitecore 9.1 to 9.2`.

Is there a way to keep xDB in MS SQL?

Is MongoDB required and is it a bad idea to keep MS SQL?

Comment: are you using MongoDB for Sitecore 9.1?

Comment: No, thats why I’m asking.

Comment: If you are already in mssql, going from 9.1 to 9.2 in mssql is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. MongoDB is legacy support now.

Best Practice is to use MS SQL for xConnect and xDB.

Answer (score 4):

You are on Sitecore 9.1 with xDB already in SQL and upgrading to Sitecore 9.2 than you don't require to use MongoDB. Even best practice is to use MS SQL or SQL Azure for xConnect and xDB, we generally try to avoid MongoDB.

The xDB Collection database can be hosted on:

- SQL Server
- SQL Azure
- MongoDB (Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 and later)

But if you really want to use the MongoDB, I would suggest you to go with MongoDB considerations - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/mongodb-considerations.html

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 9.2 gives you both options but doesn't enforce. If you have SQL in 9.1, you can keep it the same.